# Setup a Gnosis Safe on Polygon with same address, cannot execute txs

Tags: gnosis-safe, polygon, multisignature

Browser: Brave Browser

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

wallet connection: MetaMask

---

Hi there! We have deployed several instances of our multisigs on many networks, Mainnet, Gnosis Chain, Polygon, Optimism etc.. We have used the method of reusing the deployment data on the gnosis factory to get our multisig at the same address on a new chain.

This has caused no issues for creating and executing transactions between Mainnet and Gnosis Chain, however Polygon has begun causing some issues..


**This is the safe in question:**
https://app.safe.global/home?safe=matic:0x4D9339dd97db55e3B9bCBE65dE39fF9c04d1C2cd

We created a few txs to swap out some owners, take note we do get the error saying we might need to use the CLI, I was able to make the txs anyway.

[image]

we also get a plethora of 403 errors in the console from the websocket connection

[image]

When I try now to execute these fully signed transactions they do not pass and throw me this error:

**Tenderly Simulation link:**
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/890d2c86-027f-4dbe-9bd0-3883b26de360
[image]

I instead went to the CLI and via docker attempted to execute the tx from there, it threw this error then exited:
[image]

Then subsequently on the UI the tx was cancelled and removed from our queue as a result, very lame..

At this point I don't know how to reliably setup and pass txs on our multisig, what do we need to do? update the base contract? No idea..